# Javascript variable list obj.names is null when only some are null

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to get a list together from an array but some of the fields are null and it seems to be breaking there and returning:

```
obj.names is null
```

Here is the code:

My Code

```js
var data = {
  "people": [{
      "id": "32",
      "description": "some description",
      "archived": "",
      "new": 0,
      "names": [{
        "name": "name 1",
        "translations": null
      }, {
        "name": "name 2",
        "translations": null
      }],
    }, {
      "id": "56",
      "description": "some description",
      "archived": "",
      "new": 0,
      "names": [{
        "name": "name 3",
        "translations": null
      }, {
        "name": "name 4",
        "translations": null
      }],
    }, {
      "id": "99",
      "description": "some description",
      "archived": "",
      "new": 0,
      "names": null,
    },

  ]
};

var mainData = [data];
var namesList = [];

for (var i = 0; i < mainData[0].people.length; i++) {

  var obj = mainData[0].people[i];
  var nme = obj.names.name;
  namesList.push(nme);
}

console.log(namesList); //This should have the list of names
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/myfiddles2016/a3gybomr/)

How can I fix this?

Comment: `names` is an array. You will have to loop over that as well to get value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`names` is an array, you need to get the `name` property from the objects inside the `names` array.

Replace these lines

```
var nme = obj.names.name;
namesList.push(nme);
```

by

```
if( obj.names )
{
   var nme = obj.names.map( function(item){
    return item.name; 
   });
   namesList = namesList.concat(nme);
}
```

`map` method is used to iterate the array and return the `name` property of each array item.

Comment: You should include why your changes are important.

Comment: Still getting: TypeError: obj.names is null

Comment: obj.names.map will give Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null. you should rather use simple looping of javascript.

Comment: @markcc2016 some of the objects have name as null, so introduced a check for that now.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using array methods like map/reduce/forEach.

You end up with something like this:

```
// we want to loop over the people array, but it's not a 1-to-1 relation, since we want all name in the names array, so we use reduce into new array.
var namesList = data.people.reduce(function( ary, peopleRecord ) {
    // We want to concat the names from the names array to our result
    return ary.concat(
        // but if the names array is null, we have nothing to concat, so check if the names array exists 
        peopleRecord.names && peopleRecord.names.map(function( nameRecord ) {
            return nameRecord.name;
        // Or else if the names array doesn't exist, just concat an empty array to the final result.
        }) || []
    );
}, []);
```